# ConstraintLayout use ConstraintSet

Tags: android

When I migrate to `Androidx` I got an error  All children of `ConstraintLayout` must have ids to use `ConstraintSet but its worked in previous targetversion 26 when I changed the target version to 28 I got an error like this

I tried any solution but nothing is work for me, please anyone provides the solution.

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(mBinding.childConstraint);
        if (tripType == TripType.ONE_WAY) {
            mBinding.btnRoundTrip.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mBinding.btnOneWay.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.button_footer);
            mBinding.btnMulticities.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mBinding.btnRoundTrip.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_hint));
            mBinding.btnOneWay.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_home));
            mBinding.btnMulticities.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_hint));
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.depLayout, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.endBorder, ConstraintSet.START, 0);
            constraintSet.setVisibility(R.id.retLayout, View.GONE);

        } else if (tripType == TripType.ROUND_TRIP) {
            mBinding.retLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBinding.btnOneWay.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mBinding.btnRoundTrip.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.button_footer);
            mBinding.btnMulticities.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mBinding.btnRoundTrip.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_home));
            mBinding.btnOneWay.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_hint));
            mBinding.btnMulticities.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_hint));
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.depLayout, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.centerDivider, ConstraintSet.START, itemMargin);
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.retLayout, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.centerDivider, ConstraintSet.END, itemMargin);
            constraintSet.setVisibility(R.id.retLayout, View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mBinding.btnOneWay.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mBinding.btnMulticities.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.button_footer);
            mBinding.btnRoundTrip.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mBinding.btnRoundTrip.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_hint));
            mBinding.btnOneWay.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_hint));
            mBinding.btnMulticities.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.text_color_home));
        }

        constraintSet.applyTo(mBinding.childConstraint);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mBinding.childConstraint);
```

Please provide a solution quickly

Comment: give ids to all the children

Comment: whats the error you got?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: All children of ConstraintLayout must have ids to use ConstraintSet
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet.clone(ConstraintSet.java:1432)

Comment: I already add an id to all the children

Answer (score 0):

Add id to all the views in the respective xml file

Comment: All views contain the id

Comment: I already add an id to all the children but repeatedly it showing the same error